# Kotlin android if statement

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin, Android studio, v. 4.0.1

I have a progress bar in my app that ranges from 0 to 10.
When it is at 0, the following code gives an error (which is logic):

```kotlin
val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress) + 1
resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
```

So I want to add an if statement before to filter out the 0. If the progress bar is at 0, the 'rand' should be at 0 too.
I have the following but it does not work:

```kotlin
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    val ggg = seekBar.progress
    if (ggg = 0) {
        val rand = 0
    } else {
        val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress) + 1
    }
    resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand` is defined in the scope of `if` and `else`, you cannot use it outside that scope and instead of comparing `ggg` with `0` (`==`) you are setting its value to `0` (`=`). And if you want to reassign `rand`, it cannot be a `val` which can only be assigned once, make it a `var` instead.

Do it like this:

```kotlin
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    val ggg = seekBar.progress
    var rand = 0;

    if (ggg != 0) {
        rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress) + 1
    }
    
    resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I presume that there is no semicolon in 'val rand = 0;' and for the 'rand' in the if statement, the compiler says that 'Val cannot be reassigned' and the whole does not work.

Comment: Aaarg... That's a mistake by me... A `val` can only be assigned once... Wait, I'll edit it. Should have been a `var`, @Sam77

Comment: Winner! works as expected. Many thanks. I understand better also what was not working and why.

Answer (score 2):

Replace  `if (ggg = 0) {` with `if (ggg == 0) {`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better. Now the compiler says that 'rand' is an 'unresolved reference' in the last line (rand.toString() ). Does one have to pass any data out of the if statement in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

A more Kotlin approach might be along the lines of:

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    val rand = seekBar.progress.let {
        if (it == 0)
            0
        else
            Random().nextInt(it) + 1
    }
    resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
}
```

This uses an `if()` expression (not a statement) to avoid any mutable variables.  And by getting the value of `seekBar.progress` only once, it also avoids any issues if the bar gets moved while that's running.

However, I have to check if that's actually what you want:

```
Bar position | Possible values
          0  |  0
          1  |  1
          2  |  1–2
          3  |  1–3
          …  |   …
```

That looks wrong to me…  Do you really want to exclude zero in all but the first case?  If not, then you could just move the addition inside the call — `Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress + 1)` — and avoid the special case entirely.